# Fixed position html css sidebar scrolls in mobile view when not supposed to

Tags: html, css, css-position, sidebar, mobile-website

I am currently building out my portfolio, and while working on the sidebar and testing for mobile responsivness, i ran into a small problem.

i have a div that acts as my sidebar, it has a position fixed, with a top and left 0. and in desktop view, it stays on scroll and works as i would expect. however through the inspect tab, and mobile view, the sidebar scrolls with the page. Code is attached below, in a perfect world i would be able to keep the sidebar where it is supposed to be in the mobile view. and this is specific to the mobile view, if you just shrink the main window to the media query width, it works as expected. Thanks!!

EDIT:

What iwant it to look like: https://youtu.be/w3AT3WHHL4o

what it looks like: https://youtu.be/kbfS8vBKAlU

```
<div class="side-nav">
            <a href="#home" class="logo">
                <img class="logo-img" src="Images/Logo.png">
                <img class="icon-img" src="Images/Icon.png">
            </a>

            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa-solid fa-user scrollLink"></i><p>About</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="#projects"><i class="fa-solid fa-folder scrollLink"></i><p>Projects</p></a></li>
                <li><a href="#resume"><i class="fa-solid fa-file scrollLink"></i><p>Resume</p></a></li>
                <div class="active"></div>
            </ul>
        </div>



<style> 
.side-nav {
    width:  250px;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #9E9E9E;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px 30px;
}

.logo {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 130px;
}
.logo-img {
    display: block;
    width: 190px;
}
.icon-img {
    display: none;
}

.nav-links {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;

}
.nav-links li {
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.nav-links li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 14px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-links li a i {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.active {
    background: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 47px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 4%;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    display: none;
    transition: top 0.5s;
}

.nav-links li:hover a {
    color: #9E9E9E;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-links li:hover ~ .active {
    display: block;
}
.nav-links li:nth-child(1):hover ~ .active{
    top:  4%;
}
.nav-links li:nth-child(2):hover ~ .active{
    top:  35.9%;
}
.nav-links li:nth-child(3):hover ~ .active{
    top:  69.2%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:  600px){
    .side-nav {
        width: 110px;
    }
    .nav-links li a p {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav-links li a i {
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    .nav-links li a {
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .logo-img {
        display: none;
    }
    .icon-img {
        display: block;
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: i'm not sure with what you want here, so you want the sidebar to not be following scroll when you're in a mobile view?

Comment: added videos to show what i want vs what i have

Answer (score 0):

i have commented the things i added. i am sorry i would not be able to explain because you setup is very messy & need to refactored.

```css
.side-nav {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #9E9E9E;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 130px;
}

.logo-img {
  display: block;
  width: 190px;
}

.icon-img {
  display: none;
}

.nav-links {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links li {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.nav-links li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-links li a i {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.active {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 47px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 4%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  display: none;
  transition: top 0.5s;
}

.nav-links li:hover a {
  color: #9E9E9E;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.nav-links li:hover~.active {
  display: block;
}

.nav-links li:nth-child(1):hover~.active {
  top: 4%;
}

.nav-links li:nth-child(2):hover~.active {
  top: 35.9%;
}

.nav-links li:nth-child(3):hover~.active {
  top: 69.2%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .side-nav {
    width: 100px;
    height: 70vh;
    padding: 2px 3px;          /*i added*/
    display: flex;               /*i added*/
    flex-direction: column;        /*i added*/
    align-items: space-between;   /*i added*/
    
  }
  .nav-links li a i {
    font-size: 12px;       /*i added*/
    margin-right: 0px; /*i added*/
  }
  .logo {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 30px;       /*i added*/
}
  .nav-links li a p {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-links li a i {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .nav-links li a {
    justify-content: flex-start;       /*i added*/
  }
  .logo-img {
    display: none;
  }
  .icon-img {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="side-nav">
  <a href="#home" class="logo">
    <img class="logo-img" src="Images/Logo.png">
    <img class="icon-img" src="Images/Icon.png">
  </a>
  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa-solid fa-user scrollLink"></i><p>About</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#projects"><i class="fa-solid fa-folder scrollLink"></i><p>Projects</p></a></li>
    <li><a href="#resume"><i class="fa-solid fa-file scrollLink"></i><p>Resume</p></a></li>
    <div class="active"></div>
  </ul>
</div>
```